# Python + Selenium --How to find a dynamic element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm a newbie in Selenium. I'm trying to click on an element, HTML structure looks like:

```
<label>
     <span> text </span>
</label>
```

I need to click on "text" under `<span>`, this whole thing is inside another span/div/body etc. and I'm trying to make it dynamic so I can locate it with a different text as well.

And I'm using below code for it:

```
[...]
vote = input("Which option should I vote for you? :  ")
option = "//label/span[contains(.,'" + vote + "')]\""
option = str(option)
[...]
browser.find_element_by_xpath(option).click()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: There isnt really much to show... i tried:


[...]
vote = input("Which option should I vote for you? :  ")
option = "//label/span[contains(.,'" + vote + "')]\""
option = str(option)
[...]
browser.find_element_by_xpath(option).click()

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\"` in the xpath?

Comment: oh, i just got what you mean, i think thats how " can be inside a string in python.. right?

Comment: Have you tried adding waits in your code?; the element could be generated dynamically by JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Selector, however without knowing the structure of the rest of the DOM this might not be unique enough to reliably grab the element you want:

`find_element_by_css_selector("label span")`

Comment: I would like to make it so that the word can be different each time.

Comment: what im trying to do is click one of the choices a poll has, however the choice would be different its time and each answer is in a similar <labe><span>

Answer (score 0):

The extra double quote makes your xpath invalid - this one here, the escaped one:

```
 "')]\""
```

When the `option` string is constructed, the xpath ends up

```
//label/span[contains(.,'text')]"
```

, where the `"` at the end is breaking it.

Just drop it, and you'll be good:

```
option = "//label/span[contains(.,'" + vote + "')]"
```

---

You don't have to cast `option` to string - it's already of this type. Also, this way of string construction - using string formatting - is more "pythonic":

```
option = "//label/span[contains(.,'{}')]".format(vote)
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the dynamic element you can use the following solution:

```
vote = input("Which option should I vote for you? :  ")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label/span[normalize-space()='" + vote + "']").click()
```